# How to center a custom layout in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I created a navigation drawer and listed menu icons. After that I had to include a custom layout bottom of the menu list.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:layout_gravity="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                ndroid:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                ndroid:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        </FrameLayout>
   <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_view_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_prof"
            android:title="@string/my_profile" />
           ........other items here.......
        </group>
      <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item app:actionLayout="@layout/toggle_button"
            android:title="@string/blank"
            />
    </group>
```

**toggle_button.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/left_rounded"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
    android:text="@string/lang_en"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/right_rounded"
    android:text="@string/lang_ar" />
```

Then it displayed the custom layout but it is aligned right side. I need this to be aligned center horizontally. Also attached a problem illustration below.

Problem illustration

[image]

Comment: post the code for the layout file of your drawer

Comment: updated with layout xml

Comment: You still have not provided what @Sam was asking for. Where is your navigation layout file?

Comment: @H.Brooks please check now, the updated problem

Comment: so `toggle_button` is your custom layout that you want to display in the center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the internet I came up with a solution.

**Steps**

1. Included my custom layout(toggle_button.xml) in NavigationView Layout.

**NavigationView Layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:layout_gravity="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                ndroid:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                ndroid:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        </FrameLayout>
   <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

     <include layout="toggle_button.xml""/>

  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2.Updated my custom layout for making toggle aligned center in bottom.

**toggle_button.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/left_rounded"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/lang_en"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/right_rounded"
        android:text="@string/lang_ar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. Also removed the second group from **drawer_view_menu.xml**

Done! It was as simple as that....